# mySQL table to JSON array with subarrays using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am currently reading data from a mySQL table in Javascript using PHP's json_encode. My table has this format:
[image]

And this structure:
[image]

I am using this PHP code to put the into JSON form:

```
$sql = "SELECT `choice`, `choice_id`, `is_right_choice` FROM Question_choices WHERE `question_id` = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}} 
else {
echo "Congrats, You Have Displayed All the Answers!";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($rows);
```

When I call this script, I get this result:

```
[{"choice":"A","choice_id":"1","is_right_choice":"0"},
{"choice":"B","choice_id":"2","is_right_choice":"0"},
{"choice":"Correct","choice_id":"3","is_right_choice":"1"},
{"choice":"D","choice_id":"4","is_right_choice":"0"}]
```

However, I want to format my JSON so that it has an array of 'question_id' and if you call 'question_id[0] (or 1)', it will have a sub-array in it of all the 'choice' values that also have a 'question_id' of 1.

Ignore the `FROM Question_choices WHERE question_id = 1";`, that is just there to get a correct JSON call right now. In the future, my table will have many different values for 'question_id'.

In short, I want to hopefully use PHP's JSON encode to format my JSON like this
JSON:
{question_id:1{{choice:A},{choice:B}}, question_id:2{{choice:C},{choice:D}}, etc...}

Is this possible using PHP or do I have to look elsewhere?

Comment: You need `MySql JOIN` to get from one to many relation.

Answer (score 0):

This will group the choices together for each `choice_id`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `choice` ), `choice_id`, `is_right_choice`
FROM Question_choices
GROUP BY `choice`
```

Comment: I get this error when I try that command using PHPMyAdmin        #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Wine.Question_choices.choice_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Did you look into that error message and how to get around it?